# Galaxy S2 mixing up contact shortcuts after exchange password change

Tags: sync, exchange, contact-shortcut

I have a user with a Galaxy S2 running Android 4.0.4 complaining that after syncing with exchange his contact shortcuts have all been mixed up. For example a shortcut to his wife's contact when clicked now points to someone else entirely. The only solution is to delete and recreate the shortcuts each time he changes his password in exchange. Anyone else run into this very annoying bug?

Thanks for any assistance.